# Django Querystring Extract Dictonary

Tags: python, django

I want to send a post request via ajax to my django server. Within this, there is the data dictonary "inputs":

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": this.csrf },
            data: { "Intent": intent, "Inputs": inputs},
...
```

The inputs-object is something like this:

```
inputs = { "Var1": "Test1", "Var2": "Test2"}
```

Django converts the request data to a Querydict:

```
<QueryDict: {'Intent': ['18'], 'Inputs[Var1]': ['Test1'], 'Inputs[Var2]':['Test2']}>
```

I want to extract the inputs-object so that I can work with it the same way like with a python dictonary.

I've tried:

```
request.POST
request.POST.iterlist()
request.POST.get('Inputs')
dict(request.POST)
dict(request.POST.iterlist())
dict(request.POST._iterlist())
request.POST.getlist()
```

but I never got a python dict. How do I extract a object/dict of a Querydict?

Comment: `Inputs` is not a key of the data. You can only access `request.POST.get('Inputs[Var1]')` or `request.POST.get('Inputs[Var2]')`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing using `request.POST`, try using `request.body` to access the object. Then use `json.loads` to convert into a dictionary.

Or else, you can also use `request.POST.get("Inputs[Var1]")` to access the Var1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is convert [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)( a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object which is already converted by Django using request body) into a dictionary using various methods as you listed.

If you need to access *raw or non-form data* posted in the request, access it through the [**`request.body`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) attribute and use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to deserialize it into a Python object which might or might not be successful depending on the incoming data.

You are better off using [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) because [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) class is customized to deal with multiple values for the same key since keys in such data can be repeated, for instance
in the data from a form with a `<select multiple>` field.